# JS Move a Div by Scroll Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want to move a bootstrap "navbar" header off the page when the navbar's position on the page reaches 400px.

If you look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1944/), I want the `.navbar` to leave the top of the page when the blue block begins (at 400px). The navbar would stay on the page through the red div, then leave the top of the page when the blue block begins.

I have tried to do this with [scrollorama (jquery plugin)](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/), but have not had success yet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({ blocks:'.scrollblock' });
    scrollorama.animate('#fly-in',{ delay: 400, duration: 300, property:'top', start:-1400, end:0 });
});
```

I am looking for either a pure javascript solution, or with the scrollorama plugin. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the *scrollorama plugin* but you can get this done simply with jQuery via the `scroll()` event:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var redHeight = $('#red').height();
    if (winTop >= redHeight) {
    /*if the scroll reaches the bottom of the red <div> make set '#move' element
      position to absolute so it will move up with the red <div> */ 

        $('#move').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'bottom': '0px',
            'top': 'auto'
        });
    } else {
      //else revert '#move' position back to fixed

        $('#move').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'bottom': 'auto',
            'top': '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

See this updated jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1945/](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/52VtD/1945/)

---

Edit: **make it so that the navbar disappears at the same point that the red div ends**

I noticed that earlier as well but I'm having trouble locating the problem so I removed your imported style sheet and created a basic style for the navbar. To get the navbar disappears at the same point that the red div ends you need to subtract the navbar's *height* to the condition:

```
if (winTop >= redHeight - $('#move').height()) {
```

I've also restructured the markup to get this working properly. I've nested the navbar inside the red div and set the red div's *position* to `relative`.

See this jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1981/](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1981/)

Comment: Works great in the fiddle, but when I put it in my site it doesn't work for some reason. Any chance you have a quick second to check out why it won't work for me? [The Site](http://www.californiafootgolfclub.com/dev/)

Comment: yes sure, on the site when do you want the nav bar to leave the top? When the scrollbar reached the bottom of the slider?

Comment: Actually sorry made a stupid mistake: it works as in the jsfiddle. But one question is how can I make it so that the navbar disappears at the same point that the red div ends? So the navbar would not exist at all over the blue div? Currently the navbar extends into the blue div until the red div disappears..

Answer (score 0):

listen to the scroll event using jquery to find if the navbar overlaps with the red or blue div

Assign a class to the red div

```
   <div class="redDiv" style="height:400px; background-color: red;">
```

Then listen to the scroll event and use the getBoundingClientRect() to find the co-ord of the navbar and the div in the view port to check for overlap

```
   $(document).scroll(function(event)
                 {
                     var rect1 = $('.navbar').get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
                     var rect2 = $('.redDiv').get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
                     var overlap = !(rect1.right < rect2.left || 
            rect1.left > rect2.right || 
            rect1.bottom < rect2.top || 
            rect1.top > rect2.bottom)

                   if(!overlap)
                   {
                       if ( $(".navbar").is(":visible") ) {
                           $('.navbar').hide();
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        if ( !$(".navbar").is(":visible") ) {
                           $('.navbar').show();
                       }
                   }
                 });
```

Here is a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SXzf7/